# How to handle p4 submit if no open files in command line

Tags: batch-file, automation, perforce, p4v

I am doing this

```
p4 edit <list of files>
p4 revert -a
p4 submit -d "automation"
```

Now if there is no change in the default changelist the  p4 submit option fails.
How do I submit only when there is some files in default changelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you run your submit, run `p4 opened` and see if it returns any results (e.g., pipe it to `wc -l`, say).  If it does, do the submit; if it does not, skip the submit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark I got this working.Adding it below so that others can benefit

```
@echo off
p4 opened   2>&1  | findstr /I /C:"File(s) not opened on this client."  1>nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
echo "Nothing to submit"
) else (
p4 submit -d "automation submitting XXXX"
)
```